# Why does `hoist` constrain the type parameter of this monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have some function that composes two monads:

```
comp :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
```

And two instances of such monads, where on is "inside" an `Mfunctor`,

```
ms :: Monad m => m String
ms = undefined

tma :: (Monad m, MFunctor t) => t m a
tma = undefined
```

Now if I try to compose `ms` with `tma`:

```
tmas = hoist (\ma -> comp ma ms) tma
```

I am getting this error:

```
 Could not deduce (a ~ [Char])
    from the context (Monad m, MFunctor t)
      bound by the inferred type of
               comp :: (Monad m, MFunctor t) => t m b
      at Coroutine.hs:607:1-40
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context: m a -> m a at Coroutine.hs:607:8
    Expected type: m a
      Actual type: m String
```

which states that `a` in `ms` has to be of arbitrary type: `ms :: Monad m => m a`.

Why is this and is there a way to compose `tma` with monads of specific parameters.

I can see that signature of hoist is:

```
hoist :: (Monad m, MFunctor t) => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b
```

but cannot picture how `forall` is affecting what I am trying to do, if it has any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch the order of arguments to `comp` like this:

```
tmas = hoist (\ma -> comp ms ma) tma

-- or more simply:
tmas = hoist (comp ms) tma
```

The reason is that the type of `comp` is:

```
comp :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b -> m b
```

If you set, `ms` as the second argument, the `b` type-checks as a `String` and you get:

```
(`comp` ms) :: (Monad m) => m a -> m String
```

... but if you set `ms` as the first argument, the `a` type-checks as a `String` you get:

```
(ms `comp`) :: (Monad m) => m b -> m b
```

That latter type is the correct type for `hoist` since the `b` is universally quantified (i.e. "forall"ed).

To answer your question about correctness, the answer is that the universal quantification guarantees that the argument to `hoist` only modifies the monad layer and not the monad return value.  However, if it's your intention to modify the return value, too, then `hoist` is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `hoist` says that it expects a function `(forall a. m a -> n a)` i.e. a function that changes the "container" type but keeps the type parameter the same. The `forall` here  means that the function you provide cannot be specialized for any specific `a` but has to work for any type parameter.

The function you are trying to use (`\ma -> comp ma ms`) has the type `m a -> m String` so it is pretty much the opposite of what `hoist` expects since it keeps the container (`m`) the same but changes the type parameter (from `a` to `String`).

I think what you are actually looking for instead of `hoist` in this case is a function that lifts a monadic function to work on transformed monads, so instead of `MFunctor` you'll want something like:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

tmas :: (Monad m, Monad (t m), MonadTrans t) => t m String
tmas = transLift (\ma -> comp ma ms) tma

transLift :: (Monad m, Monad (t m), MonadTrans t) => (m a -> m b) -> t m a -> t m b
transLift f tma = tma >>= lift . f . return
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Does the presence of `forall` guarantee some level of correctness somehow?